# Парсинг "Google Новости"

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Программа должна распечатать все ссылки с сайта гугл-новости.

Однако при воспроизведении кода idle просто рестартится. Так же пробовал на терминале Linux - нет прогресса. Если взять модуль `requestS` вместо `request`, то выдает ошибку мол нет аттрибута (или что это) `urlopen`.

Все сделал по упражнению, ошибок грамматики нет.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request\
            .urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html,
                           parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
            url = tag.get("href")
            if url is None:
                continue
            if "html" in url:
                print("\n" + url)

news = "https://news.google.ru/"
Scraper(news).scrape()
```

Comment: Все у вас правильно. Просто с тех пор Google поменял код и сейчас у них ни одна ссылка не содержит подстроку `'html'`... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, проверил на другом сайте и пару результатов увидел. Но если все таки ужас как надо увидеть ссылки с гугл новостей, есть выход?

Answer (score 1):

"Ошибка" в том, что в ссылках [Google Новости](https://news.google.ru/) подстрока `'html'` отутствует - в итоге условие:

```
if "html" in url:
```

никогда не выполняется

---

Попробуйте так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://news.google.ru/'    
fltr = '[href*=./articles/]'

def scrape(url='https://news.google.ru/', fltr=''):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if not r.ok:
        r.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    return [{'url': urljoin(url, x.attrs['href']), 'text': x.get_text()}
            for x in soup.select(f'a{fltr}')
           ]

res = scrape(url, fltr)
for d in res:
    print(d['url'], d['text'])
```

пример вывода:

```
https://news.google.ru/articles/CAIiEPHDFAJPD7dTwqzDLwPVhK4qGAgEKg8IACoHCAowqu6gCTCp8XAwzISNAw?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU%3Aru
https://news.google.ru/articles/CAIiEPHDFAJPD7dTwqzDLwPVhK4qGAgEKg8IACoHCAowqu6gCTCp8XAwzISNAw Опубликованы кадры с камер, запечатлевших момент бойни в керченском колледже
https://news.google.ru/articles/CAIiEF57_Ti2faBT6rAqrp177fQqGAgEKg8IACoHCAowpuXNATCT2ScwiM-aAQ?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU%3Aru
https://news.google.ru/articles/CAIiEF57_Ti2faBT6rAqrp177fQqGAgEKg8IACoHCAowpuXNATCT2ScwiM-aAQ Власти объяснили задержку с похоронами керченского стрелка
https://news.google.ru/articles/CAIiENZRvPHDz_BWw0b-PGLx5a8qGQgEKhAIACoHCAowrL6iCTDPj5gCMPXWigY?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU%3Aru
https://news.google.ru/articles/CAIiENZRvPHDz_BWw0b-PGLx5a8qGQgEKhAIACoHCAowrL6iCTDPj5gCMPXWigY Керченский убийца мог украсть деньги на оружие у бабушки
...
```

Answer (score 0):

оу) Книга программиста-самоучки!
Я тоже встречаю эту проблему. Структура новостей Google действительно изменилась, и я предлагаю: заменить

```
if "html" in url:
```

with

```
if "./articles" in url: 
    url = "https://news.google.com" + url.replace(".", "")`
```

И у вас будут такие URL-адреса:

```
https://news.google.com/articles/CCAiC3Zzb2JyUEhoR2tNmAEB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
```

Они перенаправят вас на исходный источник новостей.

Мое полное решение:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url) # return site's html-code with adress url
        html = r.read() # html has site's code
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser) # parses html-code
        with open('urls', 'w') as f:
            for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
                url = tag.get("href")
                if url is None:
                    continue
                else:
                    if "./articles" in url:
                        url = "https://news.google.com" + url.replace(".", "")
                        f.write(url + "\n")
                        print(f"\n {url}")

print("In progress...")
url = "https://news.google.com/"
Scraper(url).scrape()
```

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, свой ответ на русский язык.